# Unable to change the screen brightness

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, brightness, backlight, alienware

I have an Alienware r3 15 laptop in which I've recently installed Ubuntu 17.10(dual boot with Windows 10). So far everything's fine except that I am unable to find any setting(if any) to change the brightness. There is no brightness slider in the system menu nor anything to change the brightness in "Settings". I tried installing the brightness changer indicator by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-brightness
```

but it's saying that no backlights were found on my system. I tried changing the backlight from the command line:

```
sudo echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
tee: '/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness': No such file or directory 100
```

Please help. The output of `sudo lshw -C display` on my terminal is:

```
*-display 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:125 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display
   description: Display controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Version 17.10 isn't LTS

Comment: See if this article helps: https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: I've seen this article and it didn't help. `ls /sys/class/backlight/` gives no output on my terminal and I think there is no place in the "Settings" where I can find the graphics card. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: I also didn't try creating the file given in the article because Ubuntu has switched to wayland from xorg in Ubuntu 17.10 @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: Wayland **might** be part of the problem. You can switch to X11 **if** that is the case.

Comment: Turn out that I was already using Xorg. My apologies. Still need a way for `ls /sys/class/backlight/` to work in order to try fixing my laptop using this article.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the brightness changer indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-brightness
```

after launching it should shows on your panel. click it and choose the desired value.

Another way is to do:

```
echo 1000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
```

change 1000 to desired value

Comment: i installed the brightness indicator but it's saying that no backlights were found on my system
and when I tried
"echo 1000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness"
it showed
"sudo echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
tee: '/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness': No such file or directory
100"

Comment: did the brightness work for an older version of ubuntu?

Comment: it didn't but i didn't try fixing it then either.

Comment: post the output of `sudo lshw -C display` in the question.

Comment: I have added the output in the question @ptetteh227