# Command not giving any output

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, brightness, backlight, alienware

`ls /sys/class/backlight/`
is not giving any output on my terminal. I have Ubuntu 17.10 dual booted alongside Windows 10 on my Alienware r3 15. I need to solve this issue to try to fix my main issue [Unable to change the screen brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028979/unable-to-change-the-screen-brightness) given in the article https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/. Kindly help me find a solution.

Comment: what video card do you have? do you have the drivers installed for it?

Comment: I have an 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 630' and an 'Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060' on my system.  `lspci |grep -i vga` only showed the Nvidia card though. You may check the output of `sudo lshw -C display` in my another question [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028979/unable-to-change-the-screen-brightness]. I am not sure if I have the drivers installed, at least I haven't installed them specifically. I am not sure if Ubuntu has installed it's own drivers for video cards or not @JoshuaBesneatte

Answer (score 0):

That folder is empty for me too. Look for your card type with:

System Settings->Details->About

or from the command line

```
lspci |grep -i vga
```

and then you can find what driver you are using with:

```
lsmod
```

then update/create your config according to the link you posted